# Set focus in a QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a `QMainWindow` containing a `QTableView` as its centralwidget.

I populate this `QTableView` by setting a model (which is derived from `QAbstractTableModel`).

The selection behavior for the `QTableView` is set to  `QAbstractItemView::SelectRows`. This means that if I click in a cell, the entire row is selected (and is highlighted).

I would like to be able to focus/highlight a row in the `QTableView` programatically. In other words, I would like to focus/highlight a row without the user clicking on it. How can this be done, do I 'fake' a click in a cell?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [QItemSelectionModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) of your table view, which you can get by calling the `QTableView::selectionModel()` method. QItemSelectionModel has public slot `QItemSelection::select(QModelIndex, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags)` which is changing current selection when called. So when you want to highlight particular row you can do this:

```
QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags = QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows;
QModelIndex index = m_tableView->model()->index(rowIndex, 0);
m_tableView->selectionModel()->select(index, flags);
```

You can find selection flags description [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#SelectionFlag-enum).